# How to select the right ID using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple `<form>` that should contain data URLs to redirect when the user selects a combination through the dropdown. The problem is that I have the `.click` function to run on the `<input>` which there is more than one. How should I approach this?

```
 $("input").click(function(){       
            var url = document.querySelector('#store').value;
                    console.log(url);
                    if(url != 'none') {
                    window.location = url;
                    }
        });
```

```
HTML
<form id="formname" name="Sate-Store">
                    <!-- BASIC -->
            <select name="state" class="state">
                <option value=""># of Jumpers</option>
                <option value="ma">10</option>
                <option value="me">15</option>
                <option value="nh">20</option>
            </select>
            <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="store" name="store">
                <option value>Select a room</option>
                <!-- MA -->
               <option rel="ma" value="https://www.google.com">Table</option>
                <option rel="ma" value="https://www.google.com">Private Room</option>
                <option rel="ma" value="https://www.google.com">Private Mezzanine</option>
                <!-- ME -->
                <option rel="me" value="https://www.google.com">Table</option>
                <option rel="me" value="http://www.google.com">Private Room</option>
                <option rel="me" value="https://www.google.com">Private Mezzanine</option>
                <!-- MH -->
                <option rel="nh" value="https://www.google.com">Table</option>
                <option rel="nh" value="http://www.google.com">Private Room</option>
                <option rel="nh" value="https://www.google.com">Private Mezzanine</option>
            </select>
            <input type=button value="Book Party" />
        </form>
<form id="formname" name="Sate-Store">
                        <!-- PREMIUM -->
            <select name="state" class="state">
                <option value=""># of Jumpers</option>
                <option value="ma">10</option>
                <option value="me">15</option>
                <option value="nh">20</option>
            </select>
            <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="store" name="store">
                <option value>Select a room</option>
                <!-- MA -->
                <option rel="ma" value="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Table</option>
                <option rel="ma" value="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Private Room</option>
                <option rel="ma" value="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Private Mezzanine</option>
                <!-- ME -->
                <option rel="me" value="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Table</option>
                <option rel="me" value="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Private Room</option>
                <option rel="me" value="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Private Mezzanine</option>
                <!-- MH -->
                <option rel="nh" value="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Table</option>
                <option rel="nh" value="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Private Room</option>
                <option rel="nh" value="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Private Mezzanine</option>
            </select>
            <input type=button value="Book Party" />
        </form>
<form id="formname" name="Sate-Store">
                        <!-- ELITE -->
            <select name="state" class="state">
                <option value=""># of Jumpers</option>
                <option value="ma">10</option>
                <option value="me">15</option>
                <option value="nh">20</option>
            </select>
            <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="store" name="store">
                <option value>Select a room</option>
                <!-- MA -->
                <option rel="ma" value="https://www.apple.com">Table</option>
                <option rel="ma" value="https://www.apple.com">Private Room</option>
                <option rel="ma" value="https://www.apple.com">Private Mezzanine</option>
                <!-- ME -->
                <option rel="me" value="https://www.apple.com">Table</option>
                <option rel="me" value="http://www.apple.com">Private Room</option>
                <option rel="me" value="https://www.apple.com">Private Mezzanine</option>
                <!-- MH -->
                <option rel="nh" value="https://www.apple.com">Table</option>
                <option rel="nh" value="http://www.apple.com">Private Room</option>
                <option rel="nh" value="https://www.apple.com">Private Mezzanine</option>
            </select>
            <input type=button value="Book Party" />
        </form>
```

Dropdown JS

```
$(function(){ 
            var $Pobj = $('form').parent();    
            var $cat = $Pobj.find(".state"),
                $subcat = $(".subcat");

            $cat.on("change",function(){
                var _rel = $(this).val();
                $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
                $subcat.val("");
                if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
                $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
                $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
            });
            
        });
```

Comment: Think about adding classes or IDs to your elements, then looking up how to target them with jQuery. IDs or classes will let you differentiate the inputs.

Comment: ID's should be unique. You should not have more than one tag with the same `id` attribute.

Comment: click has a `this` you can use that will give you the target element. from there, you can get the form it belongs to. you could also add whatever data- attributes you wanted and use those if there was more info you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can give the inputs an ID as such.

```
<input id="inp1" />
<input id="inp2" />
```

You can then use jQuery to reference these separately by doing the following.

```
$('#inp1').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val()) 
    // do stuff with the value
});​

$('#inp2').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val()) 
    // do stuff with the value
});​
```